# Django.In admin get values from inline

Tags: django, admin, inline

I have model "test1" and other model "test2" with fk on the first one. And i register them in admin like "test1admin" and tabular inline for "test2inline". I wanna to get access in test1admin to values of fields from inlines. I can't get values in "test1" model because instances  of "test2" wasn't created yet. I can't figure out how can i do this?